# Magento2.4.2 Url rewrites are not generated when products are assigned to new website via mass action

Tags: url-rewrite

Magento2.4.2  Url rewrites are not generated when products are assigned to new website via mass action.

Comment: You can use this extension to regenerate URL rewrites and for better options of rewriting URLs, https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites , using this you can also generate URLs for a particular store.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have used it successfully！